# NestJS + typeorm emitting record changes to frontend

Tags: nestjs, eventemitter, nestjs-typeorm

I have a use case where I would like to send record changes from backend to frontend instead of polling for changes from frontend

In the frontend I am starting a scheduled job which can take a while to finish, once the job is finished it will update the job record and I want to get the changes back to the frontend (without polling from changes)

I am using NestJS and typeorm

I have implemented a subscriber which emits the changed record like this

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class JobSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Job> {
  constructor(private readonly dataSource: DataSource, private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) {
    this.dataSource.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Job;
  }

  afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<Job>) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit('job.updated', event.entity);
  }
}
```

In the controller I am then listening to that event and doing this:

```
@Sse('/subscribe')
  @OnEvent('job.updated')
  subscribe(job: Job): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: job })));
  }
```

I have console logged that job and it outputs the record changes correctly but nothing is sent to frontend
If I change it to this it works fine and hello world is sent to frontend

```
return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } })));
```

What am I missing here ? Why is it not working ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this working was by creating an own service

```
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  private readonly emitter = new EventEmitter2();

  subscribe(channel: string): Observable<unknown> {
    return fromEvent(this.emitter, channel);
  }

  emit(channel: string, data?: object) {
    this.emitter.emit(channel, { data });
  }
}
```

The using this service in the subscriber, note that when saving entity in typeom it is possible to pass additional data, here I have passed the `uid` so that the subscription is specific to only that request

```
@Injectable()
@EventSubscriber()
export class JobSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Job> {
  constructor(private readonly dataSource: DataSource, private readonly eventEmitter: EventsService) {
    this.dataSource.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Job;
  }

  afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<Job>) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit(`${event.queryRunner?.data}/job.updated`, event.entity);
  }
}
```

then subscribing to the service, note that I am not using the `@OnEvent('job.updated')` at all

```
subscribe(uid: string): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.events.subscribe(`${uid}/job.updated`);
  }
```

and using that in the controller

```
@Sse('/subscribe')
  subscribe(@Param('uid') uid): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.jobService.subscribe(uid);
  }
```